# Sequelize unit testing with sinon

Tags: node.js

*I am trying to mock below code:*

```
 model.findAndCountAll({
            pos: start
        }).then((data) => {
         this.success(....);
        }).error(error => {
            this.error(error, this.constants.HTTP_CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        })
```

*Below is the code to mock above code:*

```
const findAndCountAll =  sinon.stub(model, 'findAndCountAll');
          findAndCountAll.withArgs().returns(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(data);
          }));
```

*If I remove error part from code to be mocked it works otherwise it gives below error:*

```
 TypeError: model.findAndCountAll(...).then(...).error is not a function
```

Comment: Is the promise defo being returned? Can you console log the result of `findAndCountAll` in your test to verify?

Comment: Yes it is returned when I remove error part. If I do not remove error part I get above error. The output with error part is undefined otherwise it outputs the response.

Comment: nvm, I've just realised what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

A [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) does not have an `error` function, you want [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
model.findAndCountAll(...)
  .then(data => { ... })
  .catch(err => { ... })
```